# useState and useEffect are not updating state with firebase data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```
export function ExplorePage(props) {
  const [videoData, setVideoData] = useState();
  const [alertMessage, setAlertMessage] = useState(null);
  const [isFetching, setIsFetching] = useState(false);
  const [newSelectedCategory, setNewSelectedCategory] = 
  useState([]);

  const fetchVideoData = () => {
    setIsFetching(true);
    let q = collection(props.videoDatabase, "videos");
    if (Array.isArray(newSelectedCategory) && 
    newSelectedCategory.length) {
      q = query(collection(props.videoDatabase, "videos"), 
      where("categories", "array-contains-any", 
      {newSelectedCategory}));
    }
    getDocs(q)
      .then(function(snapshot) {
        setVideoData(snapshot);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error.message);
        setAlertMessage(error.message);
      })
      .then(() => {
        setIsFetching(false);
      });
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchVideoData();
  }, [])

  const applyFilter = (categoryArray) => {
    console.log("reached apply filter");
    const updatedNewSelectedCategory = categoryArray;
    setNewSelectedCategory(updatedNewSelectedCategory)
  }

  const categoryList = ["food", "fashion", "cosmetics", "home", 
  "transportation", "children", "reduce waste", "clean energy"];

  return (
    <>
      <NavBar />
      <Filters uniqueCategory={categoryList} applyFilterCallback= 
      {applyFilter}/>
      {isFetching && <p>Loading videos...</p>}
      {alertMessage && <p className="bg-danger text-light p-3 mb- 
      2">Failed to fetch the data. Error: {alertMessage}</p>}
      <FairytalesList categoriesQuerySnapshot={videoData}/>
      <Footer />
    </>
  );
}
```

I am building a react app and deploying it in firebase and pulling data from the firestore database. I pass `videoData` into another component (`<fairytales>`) as a prop that then calls `map()` on it (I did not show in the image where I call `map()`, but I did show where I pass in `videoData`). When I build and deploy the app in my browser, I get an error saying:
`react-dom.production.min.js:189 TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')` coming from the `<fairytales>` component that I passed `videoData` to.
Right now, I have it so that `videoData` is initially undefined before it is updated. When I set `videoData` to be `null`, the error message then changes saying that it cannot read properties of null. Thus, I am suspecting that `videoData` is not being updated.

I am updating `videoData` with data that I get from calling `getDocs()`, which is an asynchronous function. The query I am putting in `getDocs()` is from `newSelectedCategory` which is set with `applyFilter()` which is a function called in the `<filters>` component.

I have verified that the data I am trying to get from the firestore database actually exists. I also tried calling `getDocs()` in a different file, `index.js`, and it does return data, thus further confirming my suspicion that I am getting null/undefined because the state `videoData` is not updating, and not because `getDocs()` is not working. Even though it works, I do not want to call `getDocs()` in `index.js`, so not looking for solutions suggesting that.

Also, instead of what I have right now:

```
 useEffect(() => {
    fetchVideoData();
  }, [])
```

I tried

```
 useEffect(() => {
    fetchVideoData();
  }, [videoData])
```

but that made no difference.

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code

Comment: `videoData` is undefined when the component first renders. Is `FairytalesList` prepared to handle `undefined`? Sounds like a no. Do you mean to pass `undefined` to that component or would you prefer to not render `FairtalesList` until you've retrieved `videoData`?

Comment: @AdamJenkins Sorry about that; I got rid of the picture! `FairytalesList` is not prepared to handle undefined, and I do not want to render `FairytalesList` until I have retrieved `videoData`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Set your initial `isFetching` state to `true`.
2. Move your whole `fetchVideoData` function inside the `useEffect`.
3. Don't render `FairytalesList` if `isFetching` is `true`

Your `FairtalesList` component is being rendered with `undefined` when it expects an array. The solution is to not render it until you have `videoData`.

An alternative solution is to default the `videoData` to an empty array, depends on your desired UX.